# Limit input size in chars from stdin

Tags: input, rust, user-input, stdin

I want to write an application in Rust that deals with input from terminal and I want to prevent it from crashing/being killed by running out of memory. It displays a prompt, processes a command and displays prompt again.
Basically I am looking for `read_line_max(n)` or `read_until(delimiter, max_chars)` API where at most n bytes or until delimiter is reached are read.

Possibilities I considered:

`for io::stdin().lock().take(n).lines()` takes n bytes total at most, I want unlimited chars but limit line size.

`for io::stdin().lock().lines().take(n)` limits number of lines

```
for line in io::stdin().lock().lines() {
    let line = line?.chars().take(n);
    println!("{}", respond_to(line));
}
```

too late, hogging 50GB of memory, kill imminent

I found out that BufReader used to have .chars() iterator that could be used in this way but it was removed.

With `io::stdin().lock().read(buff)` there is an issue with bytes vs chars but it may be my best bet. And then try to throw it into a String to check UTF-8 validity but that seems like something I would do in C and very unidiomatic.

Actually while writing this I quickly put together this thing:

```
let inp = io::stdin();
let mut bufinp = inp.lock();
let mut linebytes = [0_u8; 10];
loop {
    match bufinp.read(&mut linebytes) {
        Ok(bytes_read) => {
            match String::from_utf8(linebytes[..bytes_read].to_vec()) {
                Ok(line) => println!("processed line: {}", &line),
                Err(err) => eprintln!("utf8 err: {:?}", err),
            }
        },
        Err(err) => {
            eprintln!("line read err: {:?}", err);
        }
    }
}
```

So... that kind of does what I want but I have some issues with it:

1) I need to trim the '\n' if input is smaller than buffer.

2) It doesn't clear rest of the stdin if input is larger than buffer. I'm guessing I need to put a `skip_while()` there at the end so that it doesn't spill over to the next read. Is there a nicer way to clear it?

3) It may split graphemes while I could in in fact handle those additional 3 bytes. I don't really care about reading up until specific hard limit. I just want to prevent the input/memory usage from being "too much".

4) It's just too low-level and complicated and not in line with "make good and safe choices easy to code and unsafe ones less available" which makes me think I'm not doing it right. But at least `cat /dev/zero | ./target/debug/test` doesn't result in SIGQUIT anymore.

I find it strange that a language that prides itself on safety wouldn't provide a fool-proof way to deal with potentially large input. Am I missing something or thinking too much about it? Every article I found just closes its eyes and fires `read_to_end()` or `read_line()` without much thought.

How should I read user input safely and idiomatically?

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9deabc3ce550b806f53431679cb235c5 "I find it strange that a language that prides itself on safety wouldn't provide a fool-proof way to deal with potentially large input" rust will abort this is still considered safe. Except in server context I don't see much use case where you want handle memory usage.

Comment: If I insist on reading it all and memory can't be allocated then aborting is fine. What's strange to me is that the APIs that are accessible the most or patterns that are getting the most spotlight are those that do so instead of e.g. the snippet you provided. I want to handle it because application deciding to bail out for no good reason is just unsightly. And getting fed a few bytes more than usual is not a good reason.
Thank you for that. It still has the first two downsides but those were the simplest and I will pursue this direction.

Comment: "And then try to throw it into a String to check UTF-8 validity but that seems like something I would do in C and very unidiomatic." what you're trying to do is pretty much that in the first place, since you can't work at the line level because *knowing* that something is a line implies loading the entire thing into memory until the EOL, you're necessarily working at a lower level and managing the lines yourself somehow. You're also mixing bytes and strings concepts which makes the entire thing more complicated.